# Div stuck behind my header

Tags: css

I'm trying to build a generic css that I can apply to most pages on my site. I'm trying to implement parallax scrolling with banners going across the middle of the image, a header, and a footer with contact information. Currently I can't get this div to get underneath my header. Div starts at the top of the page as does the header.

Comment: Show what code you have.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. On topic and how to ask apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and provide some explanation for the code you posted.

Comment: Probably because the header is set to position: absolute/fixed. Put your code for more accurate answer..

Comment: @NotZack it's missing the link

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual ^yesssir ill get right on that

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the "z-index" style attribute for the desired division and the header and set the division's z-index to a number less than that of the header's.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Alaa,

z-index will only work on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)